# Converting hard coded JQuery to a plugin - syntax issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins, syntax

I have some JQuery that loads one of many elements, for example one `<li>` in an unordered list out of many rows of list items as such:

```
  this.randomtip = function(){
        var length = $("#tips li").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
        $("#tips li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        randomtip();
    });
```

However, I thought it would be nice to convert this to a JQuery plugin to make it more global in use so I could simply call it when I need it for different elements and use cases.

I realized I needed to take the specific selectors out and convert them to `$(this)` probably based on looking at some code of other JQuery plugins.

This is what I have so far but am getting alot of syntax errors. I have tried many different iterations of the same thing for several hours but no joy:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.randomtip = function () {

    var length = $(this).length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $(this).find (':nth-child' '+ ran + ')").show();


})(jQuery);
```

Where I am getting the syntax error is where I have:

```
$(this).find (':nth-child' '+ ran + ')").show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few typos on the `$(this).find()` line. Below is the correct version:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.randomtip = function () {
    var length = $(this).length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) + 1;
    $(this).find (':nth-child('+ ran + ')').show();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I need to add one more closing brace at the end though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax problem in

```
$(this).find (':nth-child' '+ ran + ')").show();
```

Maybe you want this?

```
$(this).find (':nth-child(' + ran + ')').show();
```